# RVM install 1.8.7 on Monterey 12.0.1 Fails

Tags: ruby, rvm, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-1.8.7

Has anyone gotten ruby 1.8.7 working on Monterey with RVM?

I've tried every solution reported out there and nothing seems to work for me. I know 1.8.7 is totally deprecated and unsupported but there are many out there still on this version.

RVM Version: rvm 1.29.12 (latest)
Gem Version: 3.2.3

Last one I attempted was:

```
$ export warnflags=-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration
$ rvm install ruby-1.8.7 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr

Warning! Requested ruby installation which requires another ruby available - installing ruby-1.8.7-p374 first.

ruby-1.8.7-p374 - #removing src/ruby-1.8.7-p374..
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system..........
Installing required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkg-config, coreutils, libyaml, libksba, readline, zlib, openssl................
Certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl@3/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Warning: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable is set, this might interact with the compilation and ruby.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.8.7-p374 - #downloading ruby-1.8.7-p374, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.8.7-p374 - #extracting ruby-1.8.7-p374 to /Users/myuser/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p374.....
ruby-1.8.7-p374 - #applying patch /Users/myuser/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.8.7/stdout-rouge-fix.patch.
ruby-1.8.7-p374 - #applying patch /Users/myuser/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.8.7/no_sslv2.diff.
ruby-1.8.7-p374 - #applying patch /Users/myuser/.rvm/patches/ruby/GH-488.patch.
ruby-1.8.7-p374 - #applying patch /Users/myuser/.rvm/patches/ruby/ssl_no_ec2m.patch.
ruby-1.8.7-p374 - #configuring...............................
ruby-1.8.7-p374 - #post-configuration.
ruby-1.8.7-p374 - #compiling.................................
Error running '__rvm_make -j12',
please read /Users/myuser/.rvm/log/1638292263_ruby-1.8.7-p374/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.

To proceed rvm requires a ruby-1.8.7-p374 compatible ruby is installed.
We attempted to install it automatically but it failed with status 2.
Please install it manually (or a compatible alternative) to proceed.
```

[Link to make.log](https://gist.github.com/oprogfrogo/e8eed424fd01b536caa368283b414948)

Answer (score 4):

These are the steps that I used to install ruby-1.8.7 on a M1 Mac running Monterey:

1. Start a Terminal window with Rosetta
2. Download and compile OpenSSL 1.0.2u (assuming it's installed to /usr/local/ssl)
3. Install HomeBrew and with it install gcc@6 (assuming you have not installed Home-brew previously in Arm64 architecture. If you have, then it needs to be uninstalled first)
4. In the terminal run :
   `rvm install 1.8.7 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/ssl --autolibs=disable --with-gcc=gcc-6`

Comment: If I'm on intel, would just steps 3 & 4 be all?

Comment: OpenSSL 1.0.2u is the highest version of OpenSSL that Ruby 1.8.7 can support so even if you are on intel, OpenSSL on your system can't be higher than that...